# Moving button above tab bar (overlap) iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Tab Bar Controller, with 3 View Controllers, and one of the VC's contain's a button that animates, but slightly overlaps the tab bar.

I have it animating nicely, but obviously the buttons sits below the tab bar in the stacking order.

What's the best way to get it to sit above the tab bar? I have tried adding it as a subview of the Tab Bar Controller, like so:

```
initialRecordButtonX = recordButton.frame.origin.x
self.tabBarController?.view.addSubview(recordButton)
recordButton.frame.origin.x = initialRecordButtonX
```

But this seems to give me an issues with alignment, the button isn't in the original buttons position, but to the top left of the screen.

UPDATE:

```
var tabView : (UIView) = self.tabBarController!.view
var btnPoint : CGPoint = recordButton.center;
var btnRect : CGPoint = recordButton.convertPoint(btnPoint, toView: tabView)
self.tabBarController?.view.addSubview(recordButton)
recordButton.frame.origin = btnRect
```

Comment: You're grabbing the button's center, converting it to a point in another rect, and then setting the button's frame's origin to its original center point.  Read that in plain-English and see if you can spot your bug.

Comment: I can't spot it at the moment. The original centre point would be set by Storyboard right? Might be missing the obvious though!

Comment: Don't use ```recordButton.center``` use ```recordButton.frame.origin```

Comment: btnRect value is now (280.0,300.0), which matches the storyboard, yet it's still top left. Could it be down to constraints? Just doing some debug, viewDidLayoutSubviews - printing btnRect, I get (280.0,300.0) and (0.0,0.0) outputted.

Comment: If you are using ```autolayout```, yes. You might need to give the recordButton layoutContraints with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a container, with the button being in a parent view controller, which fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to convert the recordButton.frame to the coordinate system of tabBarController.view.

You can use:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertPoint:toView:

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use .zPosition for the zAxis?

Therefore you can use any numbers. You can use .zPosition = 1 or with .zPosition = 9876.26. The only important thing is to make the numbers different. If the number is smaller, the element is lower / behind the other ones. If the number is larger, it is on top.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: `self.tabBar.viewWithTag(0)?.addSubview(recordButton)`